# How to change a single element in matrix?

Tags: javascript, matrix

I'm attempting to solve the 'Spiral Matrix' algorithm problem.  I'm trying to solve it by creating a reference matrix [refMatrix] that tracks where I have already been and two pointers that keep track of where I am currently in the matrix.

When I try to switch a value in the reference matrix from T to F, instead of switching just that element it switches the entire column.  I cannot figure out why.

```
const spiralOrder = function(matrix) {

    const spiralArray = [];
    const h = matrix.length;
    const l = matrix[0].length;
    const refMatrix = new Array(h)
    refMatrix.fill(new Array(l).fill(true));

    let y = 0;
    let x = 0;
    let direction = 'right';

    const movePointers = () => {
        if(direction === 'right'){
            x++;
        }else if(direction === 'down'){
            y++;
        }else if(direction === 'left'){
            x--;
        }else if(direction === 'up'){
            y--;
        }
    };

    const changeDirection = () => {
        if(direction === 'right'){
            x--;
            y++;
            direction = 'down';
        }else if(direction === 'down'){
            y--;
            x--;
            direction = 'left'
        }else if(direction === 'left'){
            x++;
            y--;
            direction = 'up';
        }else if(direction === 'up'){
            y++;
            x++;
            direction = 'right';
        }
    };

    for(let i = 0; i < (h * l); i ++){
        console.log(refMatrix); //<=========== CONSOLE LOG HERE
        if(y > h || x > l || x < 0 || y < 0){
            changeDirection();
        }else if(!refMatrix[y][x]){
            changeDirection();
        }else if(refMatrix[y][x]){
            spiralArray.push(matrix[y][x]);
            refMatrix[y][x] = false; //<====== REF ELEMENT CHANGE HERE
            movePointers();
        }
    }

    return spiralArray;
};
```

At the line indicated by my comments, it should change just one element in the matrix, instead of the whole column.

I included a console.log at the beginning of the for loop to show how the refMatrix changes every iteration.

Edit:  If I change the reference matrix to a hardcoded 'true' one, the problem goes away.  But that won't allow me to solve for varying inputs.

```
 const refMatrix = [
        [true, true, true, true],
        [true, true, true, true],
        [true, true, true, true]
    ]
```

Answer (score 1):

When I was constructing the reference matrix, every element was pointing to the same array.  When I changed one point in the array, since all 'rows' were pointing to the same array, it changed all the rows.

New 'refArray' construction:

```
 for(let i = 0; i < h; i ++){
        refMatrix.push(new Array(l).fill(true));
 }
```